# Pow works locally, but serves other site on xip.io

Tags: rack-pow

I'm using Pow.cx for local development servers - Rails, PHP and static. It's working fine locally, but when I try to use the new xip.io functionality to browse from another device I'm getting a different localhost site every time.

This particular incorrectly-served site is not set up in Pow, but I have an older virtual host set up for it.

Put another way:
stm.dev serves the correct site on my desktop.
stm.192.168.1.XXX.xip.io on my iPhone serves up a different site that is not configured in Pow.

I haven't been able to find any mention of a similar problem online, has anyone else come across this? This particular site is static html, if it matters.

Comment: Update: I tried the full xip.io address on the desktop as well with the same broken result. I get the same incorrect site that I get by typing in 'localhost' so somehow it's not connecting properly to Pow, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

So far I have been unable to get Pow to automatically pick up the xip.io addresses. However I did finally get it working to the point that I can continue building the site.

I followed the instructions from this link http://blogs.adobe.com/shadow/2012/06/19/shadow-xip-io-virtual-hosts-workflow-simplified/ in setting up a vhost alias for the site. I believe that cuts Pow out of the loop, but at least it's working now for testing on the other devices I need.

I would love to have Pow working as described, so if there are any suggestions on that end I'd love to hear it.